# Как сделать режим записи, при котором в текстовом поле добавляются ноты по нажатию на кнопки синтезатора

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer, pyaudio

Необходимо сделать режим записи, при котором в текстовом поле добавляются ноты по нажатию на кнопки синтезатора. 
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia as M
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from synt import *


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.url = None
        self.player = M.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setVolume(70)

        synthesizer = Synthesizer()
        self.window = MyWidget(synthesizer=synthesizer)

        grid = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 0, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 0, 4)
        grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 0, 5)
        grid.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        grid.setRowStretch(2, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.window, 5, 0, 1, 5)
        grid.setRowStretch(5, 1)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self,
                                     'Message',
                                     "Are you sure to quit?",
                                     QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            if self.window.synthesizer is not None:
                self.window.synthesizer.terminate()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def play(self):
        if self.url:
            self.player.play()

    def generate(self):
        self.window.synthesizer.play(self.sound_edit.text())

    def save(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()","","All Files (*);;Wav Files (*.wav)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            self.window.synthesizer.save(fileName)

    def pause(self):
        if self.url:
            self.player.pause()

    def choose(self):
        self.url, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            None, 'OpenFile', './', 'Music (*.mp3 *.wav)'
        )
        if not self.url:
            self.label.setText('')
            return
        self.url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.url)#QUrl(self.url)
        self.content = M.QMediaContent(self.url)
        self.player.setMedia(self.content)
        self.label.setText(self.url.toString().split('/')[-1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**mainwindow.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")

        self.sound_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.sound_edit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 375, 23))
        self.sound_edit.setObjectName("sound_edit")
        self.sound_edit.setText('E4_5 G3_5 B5_5 A4_5 D#3_5 G4_5 B5_5 C5_5 D4_5')

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 221, 21))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "play sound"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "pause"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open File"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save File"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "play melody"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.play)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.pause)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.choose)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.save)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.generate)
```

**synt.py**:

```
import sys
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import threading
import wave

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEventLoop, QTimer
from scipy import signal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, \
    QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from functools import partial


class Oscillator:
    def __init__(self, rate, n_chunk, freq, otype, gain=0.1):
        self.rate = rate
        self.n_chunk = n_chunk
        self.freq = freq
        self.gain = gain
        self.state = False
        self.pi2_t0 = 2 * np.pi / (rate / freq)
        self.offset = 0
        self.period = n_chunk * rate
        self.change_waveform(otype)

    def out(self):
        x = np.arange(self.offset, self.offset + self.n_chunk)
        chunk = self.gain * self.generator(self.pi2_t0 * x)
        self.offset += self.n_chunk
        if self.offset == self.period:
            self.offset = 0
        return chunk

    def is_run(self):
        return self.state

    def start(self):
        self.state = True

    def stop(self):
        self.state = False
        self.offset = 0

    def change_waveform(self, type):
        self.type = type
        if self.type == "sin":
            self.generator = np.sin
        elif self.type == "saw":
            self.generator = signal.sawtooth


class Synthesizer:
    waveform = ["sin", "saw"]

    def __init__(self, rate=44100, n_chunk=1024):
        self.rate = rate
        self.n_chunk = n_chunk
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, channels=1, rate=rate, output=1,
                                  frames_per_buffer=n_chunk)
        self.oscillators = []
        self.frames = []
        self.type = Synthesizer.waveform[0]
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.render)
        t.start()

    def __seek_osc(self, freq):
        osc = None
        for o in self.oscillators:
            if freq == o.freq:
                osc = o
        if osc is None:
            osc = Oscillator(self.rate, self.n_chunk, freq, self.type)
            self.oscillators.append(osc)
        return osc

    def render(self):
        while self.stream.is_active():
            chunk = np.zeros(self.n_chunk)
            for osc in self.oscillators:
                if osc.is_run():
                    chunk += osc.out()
                    self.frames.append(chunk.astype(np.float32).tostring())
            self.stream.write(chunk.astype(np.float32).tostring())

    def play(self, text: str):
        for s in text.split(' '):
            l = 5
            ss = s.split('_')
            if len(ss) > 1:
                l = int(ss[1])
            freq = MyWidget.pitch_freq_di[ss[0]]
            self.request(freq)
            loop = QEventLoop()
            QTimer.singleShot(l*100, loop.quit)
            loop.exec_()
            self.request(freq)

    def save(self, filename):
        wf = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(1)
        wf.setsampwidth(self.p.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paFloat32))
        wf.setframerate(self.rate)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(self.frames))
        wf.close()

        self.frames = []

    def request(self, freq):
        osc = self.__seek_osc(freq)
        if not osc.is_run():
            osc.start()
            return True
        else:
            osc.stop()
            return False

    def terminate(self):
        for osc in self.oscillators:
            osc.stop()
        self.stream.close()
        self.p.terminate()

    def change_waveform(self):
        r = np.random.randint(len(Synthesizer.waveform))
        self.type = Synthesizer.waveform[r]
        for osc in self.oscillators:
            osc.change_waveform(self.type)
        return self.type


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    pitch_class = ["A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"]
    pitch_freq_di = {pn + str(k): 440 * 2 ** (((12 * k + idx) - 48) / 12)
                     for idx, pn in enumerate(pitch_class) \
                     for k in range(0, 9)}

    def __init__(self, synthesizer=None, keyset=(39, 52, 51, 64)):
        super().__init__()
        self.synthesizer = synthesizer
        self.keyset = keyset
        self.keymap = {
            "Q": "C4", "2": "C#4", "W": "D4", "3": "D#4", "E": "E4",
            "R": "F4", "5": "F#4", "T": "G4", "6": "G#4",
            "Y": "A5", "7": "A#5", "U": "B5", "I": "C5",
            "Z": "C3", "S": "C#3", "X": "D3", "D": "D#3", "C": "E3",
            "V": "F3", "G": "F#3", "B": "G3", "H": "G#3",
            "N": "A4", "J": "A#4", "M": "B4", ",": "C4",
        }
        self.params_list = []
        print("# ================================")
        print("# Initialize")
        print("# ================================")
        self.init_ui()
        print("")
        print("# ================================")
        print("# <<Print key input>>")
        print("# ================================")
        self.show()

    def __make_bt(self, id, name):
        bt = QPushButton(name)
        if "#" in name:
            bt.key_off = lambda: bt.setStyleSheet("background-color: #999999")
            bt.key_on = lambda: bt.setStyleSheet("background-color: #9999ff")
        else:
            bt.key_off = lambda: bt.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ffffff")
            bt.key_on = lambda: bt.setStyleSheet("background-color: #9999ff")
        bt.key_off()
        bt.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        freq = MyWidget.pitch_freq_di[name]
        params = {"freq": freq, "name": name, "id": id, "self_bt": bt}
        bt.clicked.connect(partial(self.buttonClicked, params["freq"], [bt]))
        bt.setMaximumWidth(40)
        bt.setMaximumHeight(300)
        print(f"{id}\t{name}\t{freq}")
        self.params_list.append(params)
        return bt

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #eeeeee")
        self.setWindowTitle('Synthesizer')

        keys = QGridLayout()
        id = 0
        for n in range(self.keyset[0], self.keyset[1]):
            name = MyWidget.pitch_class[n % 12] + str(n // 12)
            pos = n - self.keyset[0]
            keys.addWidget(self.__make_bt(id, name), 1, pos)
            id += 1

        for n in range(self.keyset[2], self.keyset[3]):
            name = MyWidget.pitch_class[n % 12] + str(n // 12)
            pos = n - self.keyset[2]
            keys.addWidget(self.__make_bt(id, name), 0, pos)
            id += 1

        self.setLayout(keys)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 660, 160)

    def buttonClicked(self, freq, bt_list):
        sender = self.sender()
        if self.synthesizer is not None:
            state = self.synthesizer.request(freq)
            if state:
                for bt in bt_list:
                    bt.key_on()
            else:
                for bt in bt_list:
                    bt.key_off()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self,
                                     'Message',
                                     "Are you sure to quit?",
                                     QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            if self.synthesizer is not None:
                self.synthesizer.terminate()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = QKeySequence(event.key()).toString()
        bt_list = []
        freq = 0.0
        name = None
        if key in self.keymap.keys():
            v = self.keymap[key]
            for p in self.params_list:
                if p["name"] == v:
                    name = p["name"]
                    freq = p["freq"]
                    bt_list.append(p["self_bt"])
            self.buttonClicked(freq, bt_list)
            print(f"{key}: {name}")
        elif key == "@":
            type = self.synthesizer.change_waveform()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    synthesizer = Synthesizer()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWidget(synthesizer=synthesizer)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание я заменил `QLineEdit` на `QTextEdit`, просто мне кажется, так будет лучше.

Я не проверял работу других методов не связанных с кнопками синтезатора.

Я поправил фокусировку, теперь вы можете не пользоваться мышкой,
а стучать по кнопкам вашей клавиатуры.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia as M

from synt import *       

#from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")

#        self.sound_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.sound_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)                  # QTextEdit
#        self.sound_edit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 375, 23))
        self.sound_edit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 375, 50))
        
        self.sound_edit.setObjectName("sound_edit")
#        self.sound_edit.setText('E4_5 G3_5 B5_5 A4_5 D#3_5 G4_5 B5_5 C5_5 D4_5')  # -
        self.sound_edit.setText('')                                                # +
        self.sound_edit.setReadOnly(True)                                          # +
        self.sound_edit.setStyleSheet("font-size: 15px;")                          # +

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 221, 21))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "play sound"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "pause"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open File"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save File"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "play melody"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.play)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.pause)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.choose)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.save)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.generate)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.url = None
        self.player = M.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setVolume(70)

        synthesizer = Synthesizer()
        self.window = MyWidget(synthesizer=synthesizer, parent=self)          # + , parent=self

        grid = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 0, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 0, 4)
        grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 0, 5)
        grid.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        grid.setRowStretch(2, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.window, 5, 0, 1, 5)
        grid.setRowStretch(5, 1)
        
        self.window.setFocus()                                                 # +++

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self,
                                     'Message',
                                     "Are you sure to quit?",
                                     QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            if self.window.synthesizer is not None:
                self.window.synthesizer.terminate()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
        self.window.setFocus()                                                 #+++

    def play(self):
        if self.url:
            self.player.play()
        self.window.setFocus()                                                 #+++


    def generate(self):
#        self.window.synthesizer.play(self.sound_edit.text())
        self.window.synthesizer.play(self.sound_edit.toPlainText())            # toPlainText()
        self.window.setFocus()                                                 #+++

    def save(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            self, "QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()", "", 
            "All Files (*);;Wav Files (*.wav)", options=options
        )
        if fileName:
            self.window.synthesizer.save(fileName)
        self.window.setFocus()                                                 #+++

    def pause(self):
        if self.url:
            self.player.pause()
        self.window.setFocus()                                                 #+++

    def choose(self):
        self.url, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            None, 'OpenFile', './', 'Music (*.mp3 *.wav)'
        )
        self.window.setFocus()                                                 #+++
        if not self.url:
            self.label.setText('')
            return
        self.url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.url)#QUrl(self.url)
        self.content = M.QMediaContent(self.url)
        self.player.setMedia(self.content)
        self.label.setText(self.url.toString().split('/')[-1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**synt.py**

```
import sys
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import threading
import wave

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEventLoop, QTimer
from scipy import signal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, \
    QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from functools import partial


class Oscillator:
    def __init__(self, rate, n_chunk, freq, otype, gain=0.1):
        self.rate = rate
        self.n_chunk = n_chunk
        self.freq = freq
        self.gain = gain
        self.state = False
        self.pi2_t0 = 2 * np.pi / (rate / freq)
        self.offset = 0
        self.period = n_chunk * rate
        self.change_waveform(otype)

    def out(self):
        x = np.arange(self.offset, self.offset + self.n_chunk)
        chunk = self.gain * self.generator(self.pi2_t0 * x)
        self.offset += self.n_chunk
        if self.offset == self.period:
            self.offset = 0
        return chunk

    def is_run(self):
        return self.state

    def start(self):
        self.state = True

    def stop(self):
        self.state = False
        self.offset = 0

    def change_waveform(self, type):
        self.type = type
        if self.type == "sin":
            self.generator = np.sin
        elif self.type == "saw":
            self.generator = signal.sawtooth


class Synthesizer:
    waveform = ["sin", "saw"]

    def __init__(self, rate=44100, n_chunk=1024):
        self.rate = rate
        self.n_chunk = n_chunk
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, channels=1, rate=rate, output=1,
                                  frames_per_buffer=n_chunk)
        self.oscillators = []
        self.frames = []
        self.type = Synthesizer.waveform[0]
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.render)
        t.start()

    def __seek_osc(self, freq):
        osc = None
        for o in self.oscillators:
            if freq == o.freq:
                osc = o
        if osc is None:
            osc = Oscillator(self.rate, self.n_chunk, freq, self.type)
            self.oscillators.append(osc)
        return osc

    def render(self):
        while self.stream.is_active():
            chunk = np.zeros(self.n_chunk)
            for osc in self.oscillators:
                if osc.is_run():
                    chunk += osc.out()
                    self.frames.append(chunk.astype(np.float32).tostring())
            self.stream.write(chunk.astype(np.float32).tostring())

    def play(self, text: str):
        for s in text.split(' '):
            l = 5
            ss = s.split('_')
            if len(ss) > 1:
                l = int(ss[1])
            freq = MyWidget.pitch_freq_di[ss[0]]
            self.request(freq)
            loop = QEventLoop()
            QTimer.singleShot(l*100, loop.quit)
            loop.exec_()
            self.request(freq)

    def save(self, filename):
        wf = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(1)
        wf.setsampwidth(self.p.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paFloat32))
        wf.setframerate(self.rate)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(self.frames))
        wf.close()

        self.frames = []

    def request(self, freq):
        osc = self.__seek_osc(freq)
        if not osc.is_run():
            osc.start()
            return True
        else:
            osc.stop()
            return False

    def terminate(self):
        for osc in self.oscillators:
            osc.stop()
        self.stream.close()
        self.p.terminate()

    def change_waveform(self):
        r = np.random.randint(len(Synthesizer.waveform))
        self.type = Synthesizer.waveform[r]
        for osc in self.oscillators:
            osc.change_waveform(self.type)
        return self.type


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    pitch_class = ["A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"]
    pitch_freq_di = {pn + str(k): 440 * 2 ** (((12 * k + idx) - 48) / 12)
                     for idx, pn in enumerate(pitch_class) \
                     for k in range(0, 9)}

    def __init__(self, synthesizer=None, keyset=(39, 52, 51, 64), parent=None):     # + parent
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent                                                        # + parent
        
        self.synthesizer = synthesizer
        self.keyset = keyset
        self.keymap = {
            "Q": "C4", "2": "C#4", "W": "D4", "3": "D#4", "E": "E4",
            "R": "F4", "5": "F#4", "T": "G4", "6": "G#4",
            "Y": "A5", "7": "A#5", "U": "B5", "I": "C5",
            "Z": "C3", "S": "C#3", "X": "D3", "D": "D#3", "C": "E3",
            "V": "F3", "G": "F#3", "B": "G3", "H": "G#3",
            "N": "A4", "J": "A#4", "M": "B4", ",": "C4",
        }
        self.params_list = []
        print("# ================================")
        print("# Initialize")
        print("# ================================")
        self.init_ui()
        print("")
        print("# ================================")
        print("# <<Print key input>>")
        print("# ================================")
        self.show()

    def __make_bt(self, id, name):
        bt = QPushButton(name)
        if "#" in name:
            bt.key_off = lambda: bt.setStyleSheet("background-color: #999999")
            bt.key_on = lambda: bt.setStyleSheet("background-color: #9999ff")
        else:
            bt.key_off = lambda: bt.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ffffff")
            bt.key_on = lambda: bt.setStyleSheet("background-color: #9999ff")
        bt.key_off()
        bt.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        freq = MyWidget.pitch_freq_di[name]
        params = {"freq": freq, "name": name, "id": id, "self_bt": bt}
        bt.clicked.connect(partial(self.buttonClicked, params["freq"], [bt]))
        bt.setMaximumWidth(40)
        bt.setMaximumHeight(300)
        print(f"{id}\t{name}\t{freq}")
        self.params_list.append(params)
        return bt

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #eeeeee")
        self.setWindowTitle('Synthesizer')

        keys = QGridLayout()
        id = 0
        for n in range(self.keyset[0], self.keyset[1]):
            name = MyWidget.pitch_class[n % 12] + str(n // 12)
            pos = n - self.keyset[0]
            keys.addWidget(self.__make_bt(id, name), 1, pos)
            id += 1

        for n in range(self.keyset[2], self.keyset[3]):
            name = MyWidget.pitch_class[n % 12] + str(n // 12)
            pos = n - self.keyset[2]
            keys.addWidget(self.__make_bt(id, name), 0, pos)
            id += 1

        self.setLayout(keys)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 660, 160)
        
# !!!
    def buttonClicked(self, freq, bt_list):
        sender = self.sender()
        if self.synthesizer is not None:
            state = self.synthesizer.request(freq)
            if state:
                for bt in bt_list:
                    bt.key_on()
                    self.parent.sound_edit.setPlainText(                                  # +++
                        self.parent.sound_edit.toPlainText() + f'{bt.text()}_5 ')           # +++                
            else:
                for bt in bt_list:
                    bt.key_off()
                    self.parent.sound_edit.setPlainText(                                   # +++
                        self.parent.sound_edit.toPlainText().replace(f'{bt.text()}_5 ', '')) # +++                     

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(
            self,
            'Message',
            "Are you sure to quit?",
            QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No
        )
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            if self.synthesizer is not None:
                self.synthesizer.terminate()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = QKeySequence(event.key()).toString()
        bt_list = []
        freq = 0.0
        name = None
        if key in self.keymap.keys():
            v = self.keymap[key]
            for p in self.params_list:
                if p["name"] == v:
                    name = p["name"]
                    freq = p["freq"]
                    bt_list.append(p["self_bt"])
            self.buttonClicked(freq, bt_list)
#            print(f"{key}: {name}")
        elif key == "@":
            type = self.synthesizer.change_waveform()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    synthesizer = Synthesizer()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWidget(synthesizer=synthesizer)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, правда отображение надо было сделать в новом окне ниже, я исправил это, но все равно спасибо.

Comment: @Дмитрий пожалуйста